# Как запустить поток 1 раз?

Tags: java, android

При создании Activity в onCreate() запускается Servce. Service периодически возрождается, после как система  прибьет его. В Service создается новый поток (implements Runnable). Проблема в том, что поток должен быть в 1 экземпляре. Как я могу проверить существует ли поток определенного класса, и если его нет, то запустить, и наоборот, если есть не создавать поток?

UPD: Есть мысль, сделать пул потоков. Но это пока сложно для меня, можно ли сделать это проще? Контролировать 1 поток.

Comment: Сделать класс потока синглетоном.